# Calculating the angle distribution of a worm like chain

Tags: path-integral, polymers

I'm trying to calculate a probability distribution of orientation in 3D space for a worm like chain from one segment to another. In particular, I am trying to calculate the probability distribution of the angle $\theta$ between the tangent vectors one segment apart from one another. There is no particular force acting on the chain: it's just freely floating in 3D space.

All of the literature I could find on this calculation focuses entirely on the extension length, which I do not care about. I only want to know the probability distribution of a change in orientation of the tangent vector from length 0 to length 1 with some persistence length $P > 1$ (approaching $O(10)$, but still kind of order unity).

For $s \in [0,1]$ I define my unit tangent vector function $\hat{t}(s) = (1-f(s))\hat{t}(0)+f(s)\hat{t}(1)$. Theoretically, my only constraints on $f(s)$ are that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. I am trying to calculate the probability distribution of the orientation of the segment 1

I know that the probability $\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1P(\hat{t}'(s)\cdot \hat{t}'(s))ds) = \exp(-P(1-\cos{\theta})\int_0^1(f'(s))^2ds)$. If I can fully solve the integral, then I can calculate this numerically and normalize after.

My questions are two fold:

A) Is this setup of the WLC calculation valid?

B) With my persistence length reasonably bigger than 1, can I get away with pretending that my main contributor to $f(s)$ is $f(s) = s$, or do I need to do a full path integral? If the latter, how do I approach such a path integral? I have a strong mathematical background, but no experience with path integrals.